# Rails state and sleep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, sleep

I'm writing a Rails application and I'm really focusing on security. Subsequently, one approach I'm taking to reduce brute-force attacks is to `sleep 2` after any login request that fails. This adds significant time to a bot making it nearly impossible to brute force. (I'm also only allowing so many requests per IP, etc).

However, when I `sleep 2`, are all other requests also halted for 2 seconds? I know rails isn't entirely threadsafe yet (although there's a commented out option for `threadsafe!` in config files...

Is there a better approach and/or a way to only sleep for the brute forcer's thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sleeping for 2 seconds, I'd just suggest limiting the number of login attempts per IP address to limit the chance of brute force.

Setting the limit to around ten seems like a fairly good compromise to

1. Not annoy legitimate users
2. Stop brute force attacks

If this solution seems too daunting for you, there are plenty of Rails Auth libraries that have this feature built in(configurable) such as:

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

[AuthLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)

Comment: that's actually not true. I can easily write a script that randomly generates a new IP per request, so that doesn't help much. It's not a legitimate application, but one designed to teach students how to prevent and respond to intrusion attempts. also, i despise authlogic or devise or even nifty auth. SO is littered with people who use a pre-built auth and have no clue how it works. its really annoying.

Comment: I agree 100% on the pre built libraries, however I think it's a perfectly fine method to implement. I'm not claiming this to be the only one, however it is not just some academic idea to teach students. This idea has been implemented in most security systems, even core systems such as iptables and deny host.